# Heroku Database connection

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Me and another person have two different Heroku apps but I want to addon his/her app's postgres database to mines so that we share one database

I tried to add him to collaborate but collaborated user can't access addons of other owner's app

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can share the addon with the other app:

```sh
heroku addons:attach your-app::DATABASE_URL --app your-friends-app
```

Then your friend would have to promote that database as the primary in his/her application.

There are more details here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql